in Flutter Project: "Failed to Inflate ColorStateList"
Can someone please help me...
I'm working on integrating the Google Pay button in my Flutter project, but I'm encountering an issue.
Despite trying various things and making several changes, nothing has worked.
I defined a new theme, added dependencies, and installed the latest version of Android:
I am encountering the following error when trying to open the screen with the Google Pay button:
child: GooglePayButton(
    paymentConfiguration: googlePayConfig,
    paymentItems: [...],
    // theme: GooglePayButtonTheme.light,
    type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
    onPressed: () {
        return;
    },
    onPaymentResult: (result) async {
        ...
    },
    onError: (error) {
        ...
    },
),

I defined the theme...
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Adicione outros atributos conforme necessário -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">?colorAccent</item>
    
</style>

<style name="PayButtonLightTheme" parent="NormalTheme">
    <!-- Defina atributos específicos para o botão de pagamento aqui -->
</style>

In the dependencies, I have:
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

    //https://dev.to/aseemwangoo/google-pay-in-flutter-3mfh
    //https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=play-services-wallet#com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.2.1
    // implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.0.0"

    /*
        https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

        https://play.google.com/sdks/details/com-google-android-gms-play-services-wallet?hl=en-AU

    */

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'     
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.8'



    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.4.0'

    //added 2-8-2024
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0'

    //https://docs.stripe.com/google-pay
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.37.4'

    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports?authuser=0#add-plugin
    //step 1
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    // implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
    // implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2"))



    // Add the dependencies for the Crashlytics NDK and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

}

flutter --version
    Flutter 3.22.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    Framework • revision b0850beeb2 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
    Engine • revision 235db911ba
    Tools • Dart 3.4.4 • DevTools 2.34.3    


sdkmanager --list
    Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
    [=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
    Installed packages:
      Path                                                  | Version | Description                                | Location
      -------                                               | ------- | -------                                    | -------
      build-tools;30.0.3                                    | 30.0.3  | Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3             | build-tools\30.0.3
      build-tools;34.0.0                                    | 34.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 34                 | build-tools\34.0.0
      build-tools;35.0.0                                    | 35.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 35                 | build-tools\35.0.0
      cmdline-tools;latest                                  | 13.0    | Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)    | cmdline-tools\latest
      emulator                                              | 34.2.16 | Android Emulator                           | emulator
      platform-tools                                        | 35.0.1  | Android SDK Platform-Tools                 | platform-tools
      platforms;android-31                                  | 1       | Android SDK Platform 31                    | platforms\android-31
      platforms;android-33                                  | 3       | Android SDK Platform 33                    | platforms\android-33
      platforms;android-34                                  | 3       | Android SDK Platform 34                    | platforms\android-34
      platforms;android-35                                  | 1       | Android SDK Platform 35                    | platforms\android-35
      sources;android-34                                    | 2       | Sources for Android 34                     | sources\android-34
      sources;android-35                                    | 1       | Sources for Android 35                     | sources\android-35
      system-images;android-34;google_apis_playstore;x86_64 | 13      | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom System Image | system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64
      system-images;android-35;google_apis_playstore;x86_64 | 7       | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom System Image | system-images\android-35\google_apis_playstore\x86_64

The error I'm getting is:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7b040084 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7b1100a8com.google.android.gms:style/PayButtonDarkTheme], Themes=[com.google.android.gms:style/PayButtonDarkTheme, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

full error:
D/EGL_emulation(30932): app_time_stats: avg=268.36ms min=13.34ms max=9032.24ms count=36
W/FirebaseContextProvider(30932): Error getting App Check token. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
W/FirebaseContextProvider(30932): Error getting App Check token. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
W/FirebaseContextProvider(30932): Error getting App Check token. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
I/DynamiteModule(30932): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.wallet_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.wallet_dynamite:242835000
I/DynamiteModule(30932): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.wallet_dynamite, version >= 242835000
V/DynamiteModule(30932): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
E/ThemeUtils(30932): View class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
E/ThemeUtils(30932): View class com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
W/ResourcesCompat(30932): Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
W/ResourcesCompat(30932): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7b040084 a=-1}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7b1100a8com.google.android.gms:style/PayButtonDarkTheme], Themes=[com.google.android.gms:style/PayButtonDarkTheme, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.jf.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):18)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.jf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):24)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.jb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):126)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):31)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):2)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:866)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1018)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:973)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1135)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1096)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1096)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1096)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1096)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:694)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.bdv.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):337)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.bdv.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):30)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.gms.wallet.dynamite.PayButtonCreatorChimeraImpl.newPayButton(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):51)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.bdl.z(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):43)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at m.rz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@242835041@24.28.35 (190800-0):21)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1183)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zza.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.3.0:2)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.gms.wallet.button.zze.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.3.0:4)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.gms.wallet.button.zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.3.0:6)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.google.android.gms.wallet.button.PayButton.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@19.3.0:17)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.plugins.pay_android.view.PayButtonView.buildPayButton(PayButtonView.kt:61)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.plugins.pay_android.view.PayButtonView.<init>(PayButtonView.kt:48)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.plugins.pay_android.view.PayButtonViewFactory.create(PayButtonViewFactory.kt:27)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:523)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createForTextureLayer(PlatformViewsController.java:197)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:128)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:55)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
W/ResourcesCompat(30932):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
E/ThemeUtils(30932): View class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
E/ThemeUtils(30932): View class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
I/PlatformViewsController(30932): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 3
I/PlatformViewsController(30932): PlatformView is using SurfaceProducer backend
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(30932): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.wallet.service.BIND
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(30932): app_time_stats: avg=9980.78ms min=9980.78ms max=9980.78ms count=1
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/ThemeUtils(30932): View class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
E/ThemeUtils(30932): View class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(30932): app_time_stats: avg=16.54ms min=2.20ms max=79.91ms count=53
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(30932): app_time_stats: avg=1715.61ms min=3.71ms max=8534.02ms count=5
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation(30932): app_time_stats: avg=267.91ms min=9.53ms max=8570.71ms count=34
D/EGL_emulation(30932): app_time_stats: avg=259.89ms min=4.39ms max=8572.61ms count=34
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(30932): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
W/System  (30932): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(30932): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
D/TrafficStats(30932): tagSocket(303) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/FirebaseAuth(30932): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 0PuYnnjGIqegZpksE9l9Z5JcFr02 ).

++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++
I find this very suspicious. --- FrameBuffer.cpp:3544] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
It works for Pixel 8, but the posted error occurs for Pixel 7.
emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_34 -grpc 8554
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 1960
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Android\sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 24656
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 192.168.1.1
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: d0bb:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: d0bb:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 30cb:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 30cb:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 48d1:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 48d1:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: a0dd:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: a0dd:c352:d401:0:d0bb:c352:d401:0 (2x)
INFO    | Critical:
INFO    | Warning:
INFO    | Warning:  (6x)
INFO    | Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
library_mode host gpu mode host
INFO    | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoGPU #1
  Make: 10de
  Model: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU
  Device ID: 2820
I0807 10:02:36.268811   25552 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
added library vulkan-1.dll
createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
I0807 10:02:36.534453   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
I0807 10:02:36.534630   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: true
I0807 10:02:36.534820   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
I0807 10:02:36.534916   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
I0807 10:02:36.535079   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
I0807 10:02:36.535224   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
I0807 10:02:36.535409   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
I0807 10:02:36.535491   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
I0807 10:02:36.535554   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
I0807 10:02:36.535611   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
I0807 10:02:36.535725   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
I0807 10:02:36.535788   25552 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
I0807 10:02:36.537245   25552 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
I0807 10:02:36.537362   25552 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2)
I0807 10:02:36.537488   25552 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 536.67)
I0807 10:02:36.537692   25552 FrameBuffer.cpp:509] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_EXT_multiview_texture_multisample GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_buffer
I0807 10:02:36.537937   25552 FrameBuffer.cpp:510] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
INFO    | Sending adb public key [xxxxxxxx....]
WHPX on Windows 10.0.22631 detected.
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
INFO    | Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
INFO    | Using security allow list from: C:\Android\sdk\emulator\lib\emulator_access.json
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at [::]:8554, security: Insecure, auth: none
netsimd I 08-07 09:02:37.702 rust_main.rs:96 - netsim artifacts path: "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\netsimd"
netsimd I 08-07 09:02:37.702 rust_main.rs:99 - NetsimdArgs {
    fd_startup_str: None,
    no_cli_ui: true,
    no_web_ui: true,
    pcap: false,
    disable_address_reuse: false,
    hci_port: None,
    connector_instance: None,
    instance: None,
    logtostderr: false,
    dev: false,
    vsock: None,
    config: None,
    test_beacons: false,
    no_test_beacons: false,
    no_shutdown: false,
    version: false,
}
INFO    | Activated packet streamer for bluetooth emulation
WARNING | Failed to setup emulator in a timely fashion!
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_24656.ini
I0807 10:02:41.863630   24236 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2400 dpiX 420 dpiY 420
I0807 10:02:41.866370   24236 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
INFO    | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
INFO    | Successfully loaded snapshot 'default_boot'
E0807 10:02:45.020262   13816 FrameBuffer.cpp:3544] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
E0807 10:02:46.508263   18004 FrameBuffer.cpp:3544] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
E0807 10:03:49.097481   13816 FrameBuffer.cpp:3544] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
INFO    | Wait for emulator (pid 24656) 20 seconds to shutdown gracefully before kill;you can set environment variable ANDROID_EMULATOR_WAIT_TIME_BEFORE_KILL(in seconds) to change the default value (20 seconds)
INFO    | Saving with gfxstream=1


this issue is not related with the Google Pay button, but your theme definition. Here are a few pointers:

The Google Pay button in Flutter does not need any Android-based theming properties. The GooglePayButtonTheme is an enum to help you determine your preferred button style.
The issue you are seeing appears to be related to a style named PayButtonDarkTheme you are defining in your application. Review the definition and properties and ensure they are accurate.


I updated the post, I have a suspect ...
